# How to convert data frame pandas into list in numpy without word "list" in array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have converted data frame in pandas into list in numpy but I got word "list" in array numpy like in the figure 1.
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmaf5.png)

I  hope i get list data in numpy like the figure 2  without word "list" in array

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FSVk.png)

Comment: Hi, please do not post code and/or output as an image. Instead, place code and output in your question body in text. This helps others analyze and answer your question quicker and easier.

Comment: The frame column/Series contains lists, not the usual single values.  An array from such a Series will be a 1d array containing those lists.  That's what the image shows.  If you use `to_list()` instead you'll get a list of lists.  That can be turned into a 2d array **if** all those sublists have the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks `numpy.array` coerces list of lists into a 2d-array, but Series of lists into a 1d-array of lists as you get.

So this should work.

```
tweet = TWEET_DATA['TF_IDF_Vec']
arr = np.array(tweet.to_list())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
arr = np.array(tweet.tolist())
```

Answer (score 1):

The word `list` in your array display isn't just there to make things ugly.  It's meant to convey useful information.  `pandas` on the other hand tends to hide that information in its display - making things pretty.  Where possible try to understand the underlying nature of the objects you are working with, not just their display.

We can make a Series (or dataframe column) that contains a mix of items:

```
In [27]: s =pd.Series([None, 'string','[1,2,3]',[1,2,3],np.array([1,2,3])])
In [28]: s
Out[28]: 
0         None
1       string
2      [1,2,3]
3    [1, 2, 3]
4    [1, 2, 3]
dtype: object
```

Notice how the list and array appear the same, and the strings don't have quotes.

If we ask for an array from it:

```
In [29]: np.array(s)
Out[29]: 
array([None, 'string', '[1,2,3]', list([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3])],
      dtype=object)
```

`np.array()` does the same as:

```
In [30]: s.to_numpy()
Out[30]: 
array([None, 'string', '[1,2,3]', list([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3])],
      dtype=object)
```

In this 1d array the nature of the elements is more explicit.

A list of the items is similar except for the display of the nested list:

```
In [31]: s.tolist()
Out[31]: [None, 'string', '[1,2,3]', [1, 2, 3], array([1, 2, 3])]
```

We can make a 2d array from the last 2 items, because they both have length 3:

```
In [32]: s[3:].tolist()
Out[32]: [[1, 2, 3], array([1, 2, 3])]
In [33]: np.array(s[3:].tolist())
Out[33]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works

Example

```
lista = list([list([1,2,3]),[2]])

lista=sum(lista, [])

arrayLista = np.array(lista)
```

In your case

```
tweet = sum(tweet, [])
arr = np.array(tweet)
```